# Is it possible to use root build.rs to generate a workspace member Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Initially I have following files

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── build.rs
└── src
    └── lib.rs
```

in Cargo.toml

```
...

[workspace]
members = [
    "to_gen",
]
```

Now I want to use build.rs to generate the member of "to_gen" and then build it.

```
# run cargo build to generate the code first and then compile
cargo build --workspace
```

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── build.rs
├── to_gen (generated with build.rs)
|    └── Cargo.toml 
|    └── src
|        └── lib.rs
└── src
    └── lib.rs
```

But I got error failed to load manifest for workspace member. So it reads the member's Cargo.toml first. Is it possible to run the build script first?

Comment: Maybe this is a case for [`xtask`](https://github.com/matklad/cargo-xtask)?

Comment: Maybe in addition to the folder, you have to generate the `"to_gen",` entry in `members`.

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically create workspace crates? This screams XY-problem.